# jQuery: object[property].push() modifies old object if the new one is created with jQuery.extend()

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

Consider this example code:

```
a={};
a['herp']=['derp'];

var b = jQuery.extend({}, a);
b['herp'].push('foo');
alert(a['herp']); //this produces message box with "derp,foo"
```

It is my understanding that `var b = jQuery.extend({}, a);` clones an object (as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/122704/710356) by John Resig), i.e. creates a new object with the same properties as the previous. If this is correct, then why does `b['herp'].push('foo');` modify `a`, as indicated by `alert(a['herp']);`?

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/M48tr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should do:

```
var b = jQuery.extend(true, {}, a);
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/M48tr/1/

this is because the property is an array and you need a deep clone. As it is written in the documentation:

> The merge performed by $.extend() is not recursive by default; if a
>   property of the first object is itself an object or array, it will be
>   completely overwritten by a property with the same key in the second
>   object.The values are not merged.However, by passing true for the
>   first function argument, objects will be recursively merged.

If you don't do a deep copy,  `b['herp']` just contain a reference to the array that is in `a['herp']`

Things are different if the properties are not arrays or objects like in this example:

```
a={};
a['herp']='derp';

var b = jQuery.extend({}, a);
b['herp'] = 'foo';
alert(a['herp']);//alerts derp

alert(b['herp']);//alerts foo
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/M48tr/2

Comment: I just tried this and yes, it worked. It seems that this creates a 'deep' copy. But what does this mean? What's the difference between shallow and deep copy? I couldn't find anything via Google on that matter.

Comment: @exizt i updated my answer. The fact is that the porperty is an array and so it needs deep cloning

Answer (score 1):

You should read more carefully and use google. In general [Shallow copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy) - a new "copy" is created. But points to the same piece of memory(data - variables, constants, etc). Thus representing a "synonym" of the original object. And now the important thing - no matter which one you change, it will affect both.

[Deep copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy) is more time consuming because ***all*** of the data of the original object is copied into the new object. The 2 objects have the same structure (rather than pointing to the same). But changes will affect only one of the objects.

Comment: So is `var b = jQuery.extend({}, a);` essential synonimical to `var b = a`?

Comment: A shallow copy would work if the properties were not arrays or objects in this case. http://jsfiddle.net/M48tr/2/

Comment: @exizt no it depends on what values the properties of a hold. I added some more code to my answer